# Coherence Delete Entry with regular expression

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I want to delete records in namedCache in which "key" value ends with special string like

```
key1AA-BB
key2AA-BB
key3AA-BB
```

is there simple way to delete all records whose key value ends with `"AA-BB"`?

in my expreriment I have found that there is Filters (`LikeFilter` ..etc) but these filters are appied into "value" rather than "key".
Whay similar Filter logic cannot be appied based on key?

I can iterate all keys and find macthed keys, but there should be more OO way

```
      Set set = cache.keySet();
      Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(iterator.next());
//match key  cache.remove(key)
      }
```

Using: Coherence 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use KeyExtractor,

```
LikeFilter filter = new LikeFilter(new KeyExtractor(),"BB", '\0' , false );
```

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHJR/index.html